# jquery: Hide button when page = 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a next and previous page function using **jquery**. what I want to do is hide the previous button when the **page = 1**. I haven tried to create an if/else function but doesn't work. I hope you can help me and thank you for your time.

Below is my current **jquery** code:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
        page = 1;
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        getPage(++page);
    });
    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        getPage(--page);
    });
    var getPage = function (page) {
        $wrap.load('site/proxy.php?page=' +     page + ' #postsArea');
    };
    getPage(page);
});
```

Below is my **HTML** code:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:800px; width:480px;"></div>
    <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
</body>
```

Below is the **jquery** code I badly created:

```
if ((page)= 1) {
    $('input[id=prev]')
        .click(

    function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
} else {
    $('input[id=prev]')
        .click(

    function () {
        $(this).show();
    });
}
```

Below is working **jquery** code:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
        page = 1;

    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        getPage(++page);
    });
    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        getPage(--page);
    });
    var getPage = function (page) {
        $wrap.load('site/proxy.php?page=' +     page + ' #postsArea');
        if (page == 1) {
            $("#prev").hide();

        } else {
            $('#prev').show();
        }

    };
    getPage(page);

});
```

Comment: Change if ((page)= 1)  to if ((page)== 1)

Comment: @AwladLiton Thank you for your reply but the button is still visible

Comment: "It won't work" doesn't show enough effort on your part. Do some debugging.

Comment: Could you please update your question with full js code together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this js:**

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/c5bA4/7/

```
        $('document').ready(function () {
            var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
                page = 1;
    
            $('#next').on('click', function () {
                getPage(++page);
            });
            $('#prev').on('click', function () {
                getPage(--page);
            });
            var getPage = function (page) {
                $wrap.load('site/proxy.php?page=' +     page + ' #postsArea');
                if (page == 1) {
                    $("#prev").hide();
    
                } else {
                    $('#prev').show();
                }
    
            };
            getPage(page);
    
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

`if ((page)= 1)` is doubtless wrong. Perhaps you meant `if (page == 1)`.

- `=` performs assignment
- `==` performs a check for (loose) equality

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: @Awlad: What? No, it shouldn't. This is my suggestion of a code change to make to fix the code. That is, _an answer_. But I really appreciated you stealing my answer for your _own_ comment, that's great.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your reply but the button remains visible

Comment: I saw your answer after i posted my comment. I did this type of answer in another question and i got 2 down vote for this

Comment: This is not really answering question. Talking about `load()` callback to check for page === 1 would answering the question  EDIT: indeed, no need to use the load complete callback

Comment: @Awlad: Sorry to hear that. It depends on the question. Perhaps the answer was simply _wrong_? Doesn't mean it wasn't an answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Maybe I got it wrong, but this was still intended as an answer. There is a difference between "a wrong answer" and "not an answer" :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit for me, you are fixing bad OP's code, which makes it not a wrong answer so i guess in some way you are correct

Answer (score 1):

make a single click handler and use the page type condition within it.

```
$('input[id=prev]')
        .click(

    function () {
    if (page == 1) {
        $(this).hide();
        }
    else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not just:

```
var getPage = function (page) {
        $wrap.load('site/proxy.php?page=' +     page + ' #postsArea');
        $('#prev').toggle(page !== 1);
    };
```

You could set code inside `load()` complete callback but i don't see any reason here.

Answer (score 1):

Well. as you have asked to make it invisible when page == 1 you could simply put it inside the click event of `#prev'

```
 $('#prev').on('click', function () {
     if(--page <= 1 ) $(this).hide() 
     getPage(page);
 });
```